# how to specify a key file (key.json) in the url of creating a googlesheet

Tags: rest, google-sheets, postman

i have created a google service account, created a keyfile (key.json) and now I want to create a googlesheet using postman

[https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets&private-key-file=c:\temp\key.json](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets&private-key-file=c:%5Ctemp%5Ckey.json)

But I keep getting a 401 error - missing required credential

> ```
> {
>     "error": {
>         "code": 401,
>         "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
> ```
>
> authentication credential. See
> [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
> "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
> }
> }

what's the syntax to pass the key file in the url/header or body ?
thanks !

Comment: Hi, the error message you provided says you need a 0Auth 2 token. Have a look at the authorization tab on your request. In the type drop down you can select 0Auth 2. You can also check [the postman documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#oauth-20).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you using postman? I can offer you a good assistance if you explain me the general purpose you have.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

just goto authorization header and add the key and value as api key and select add in as "query parameter"

You can also manually add key and value as query parameter

[image]

Both does the exact same thing

Comment: no luck here, please see attached how i filled the Authorization tab of postman and the result.
I have also attached a (modified) key file that i got from the google developer console as a service account.
I assume that in the field 'Key' they mean "private_key_id" and in the field 'value' they mean 'private_key" ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3w74caeva0o91j3/googlesheet-service-account-key-file-example.jpg?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wde4torq34xszi/postman-authorization-screen.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You need ,auth 2 not api key

Comment: ok,the documentation says that with a service account you need to use the prive/public key json created but i'm happy to try again with oAuth2.
I can send a authorisation request to googleAuth and it returns a screen asking me authorization but then i end up in my google account. How/where can I retrieve that AuthorizationCode I need to request the token

Comment: ok,the documentation says that with a service account you need to use the prive/public key json created but i'm happy to try again with oAuth2.

I have set the redirect_uri = https://myaccount.google.com with client_id,scope,response_type=code, access_type=offline

So I send a authorization request to googleAuth and it returns a screen asking me authorization but then i end up in my google account. How/where can I retrieve that AuthorizationCode I need to request the token. 

many thanks

Comment: Why do you want to create Spreadsheets with a service account? Could you give more details about your project?